# Can I use Observer/Observable and Listener in MVC Java?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm making a game in Java (this is my first experience with Java and an Object Oriented language). The game implements the MVC design pattern. Now I have a questions. Can I use the pattern Oserver/Observable between the Model and the View (for the view I use Swing's libraries) and Listener between View and Controller? The View has a lot of buttons. During the game there is a map with some areas and road. The player, to play the game, must click on an area or a road and then decide the action to do. What is the best solution? If you don't understand I'll try to explain better the game.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question was easy enough to answer, and I felt having the answer here did add value for StackOverflow, but typically you should ask specific questions, where you have already researched the problem, tried some code and are truly stuck. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Observer pattern in Java is implemented using events and listeners. You just need to [set up listeners for the events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) you want, and you are away.

1. Events pass (to the listener method) an argument which inherits from `java.util.EventObject`, and these contain the information about the particular event.
2. Listeners are an object (concrete, or anonymous) which implements a listener interface containing one or more methods that are invoked when an event occurs
3. [Adapter classes](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/listeners_vs_adapters), such as `WindowListener` provide pre-implemented superclasses for interfaces with multiple listener methods, allowing you to inherit and only implement the one or two you want.
4. Event listeners are frequently implemented using [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

For example, listening to a click event on a button:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // this is an "anonymous class"
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO: do something
    }               
});
```

You can generate your own event sources as well, so you can use the Observer pattern throughout to watch for changes to objects and update the UI, and also to react to UI events. "Listener" was not a formal GOF pattern, but in Java listener refers to the interfaces and objects used to react to events.

Comment: So, if I understand well, I can use notifyObservers() in the model and the method update() in the view to upgrade the GUI. In other way I can use ActionListener (or I can implements my listener) to communicate between the view and the controller. It is correct?

Comment: Hi SimoneMontalto, welcome to SO. Please see my comment to your question. Your comment above needs to be a new question where you have tried some code, done your research and can't get it to work. Post your problem and problem code, then we can answer your question. You'll find people here very helpful and willing to put effort into helping you if you demonstrate effort before you ask a question. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. But I've written some code but I haven't found the solution, because there are a lot of buttons to implements and I would avoid to put a lot of if to understand which button is been pressed. I make an example. In the map there are 30 buttons and three categories of buttons (10 that call a method, 10 another and so on). Each button pass different information to the method. Can I manage this situation avoiding a cascade of if in the class that must manage the pression of the buttons?

Comment: No problem. Questions don't cost you anything, and that is definitely a new question so I would go ahead and ask it as a new one. I'll keep an eye out for it.